# Error saying pgzrun.exe is installed in a directory not in PATH

Tags: python

PGZRUN wont import for some reason, and think it has to do with this error message

```
WARNING: The script pgzrun.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\brade\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you import moduls, they have to be in PATH or in your cwd( current work directory) or in the python directory

1. to [add a directory to path](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html) you have to modifiy th PATH environmental variable, appending your directory (is suggested to add python directory in PATH in EVERY case).
2. to add at the cwd you have to movw you package to the directory of your script but it isn't adviced
3. the best choice is to move the package to the directory where you have your python interpreter ( but in any case add Python directory in PATH)

Comment: How do i do that?